# Regular expression replace filenames

Tags: regex, expression, notepad++

I have a large XML file, with many references to different file names, all PDF files. I want to replace all the different file names, with the a specific file name. I am using *Notepad++*.

For example:

```
cat.pdf
dog.pdf
bird.pdf
```

Replace all these with `whale.pdf`.

I have googled, searched, tried and failed for so long right now, and I cannot make it work. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: We cannot help if you do not show what you currently got...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
\w+\.pdf\b
```

Replace with `whale.pdf`.

[image]

Comment: @malin: Great, then please consider accepting the answer (a tick on the right below the down arrow.)

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically intend to match several names you can do that in this way:

```
(cat|dog|bird)\.pdf\b
```

Comment: Please test before you post. Notepad++ is not JavaScript. http://imgur.com/qDLLi8M

Comment: OK, tested. C'mon, just leave out the slashes...`(cat|dog|bird)\.pdf\b`. That's really not too much to ask for.

Comment: And you have not edited your post yet? If I were a furious downvoter, I'd already have clicked the down arrow.

Comment: sorry, I'm not much used to this yet, didn't think of editing. Thanks that you are not furious easily.